# How to run monero-wallet-rpc in background without revealing my password to the server?

Tags: rpc, monero-wallet-rpc, ubuntu, password-confirmation, background

I know that I can run the Monero RPC wallet in the background on Ubuntu by adding a `&` to the command or by using `setsid`.

But that would result in me having to use the following code on the command line:

```
./monero-wallet-rpc --daemon-address node.moneroworld.com:18089 --rpc-bind-port 18085 --wallet-file MyMonero --disable-rpc-login --password MYPASSWORD &
```

and thus, my wallet password is viewable using `htop` or other tools. Also, it’s visible in the command line history.

Do you have a better solution?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is to run it with `--wallet-dir` option instead. Then use the `open_wallet` RPC when you're ready to use it.

Comment: maybe the best solution for now…

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a recent addition but in 0.12 and 0.13 I have been using the command line argument `--prompt-for-password`, which causes it to prompt for the wallet password when starting.